# How i can put $_GET codes in function.php?

Tags: functions, redirect, code

```
if(isset($_GET["link"])){
$link = $_GET["link"];
header("Location $link");
}
```

this my redirection codes. i put this code in function.php but not working.

Example link: http://localhost/?link=http://www.google.com

How can i do it for working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function custom_function_redirect() {
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'link' ] ) && $_GET[ 'link' ] != '' ) {
    wp_redirect( $_GET[ 'link' ], 301 );
}else{
    die('test');
 }
}

add_action('template_redirect','custom_function_redirect');
```

Try this it worked for me.

For redirection you should hook the function in template_redirect

Comment: you'd better use `! empty( $_GET[ 'link' ]  )` here http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php instead of `isset() and != ''` and maybe `wp_safe_redirect()`

Comment: That can work too

Comment: What if `$_GET` doesn't exist? Think CLI. What if the value is an array? What if it contains malicious code?